# Parallel processes with dependency

Tags: concurrency, uml, fork-join, activity-diagram

There are two parallel processes. Each process has two steps. The second step of the first process is always executed after the first step. The second step of the second process is performed only under a certain condition.

Activity diagram:
[image]

How to reflect an additional condition: to complete the second step of the second process, the first step of the first process must be completed.

I managed:
[image]

Flaws:

1. No match between fork and join
2. If the condition of the second process is not met, the token “hangs” before join

Comment: To make sure I understand correctly: it is possible, that the P2S2 is omitted entirely (if the decision node triggers the flow skipping entirely the P2S2), right?

Comment: Yes, it is possible

Comment: Isn't this problem solved if you move the decision to after the first join?

Comment: @Geert Bellekens Suitable only for this particular case. If you add a third step to the second process, which is always performed (in the diagram after the Merge Node), then it does not work.

Answer (score 2):

Having looked at your solution once more made me think that you saw issues, where there are none. You are worried about the hanging token, but that is no issue in this case. If P22 is bypassed, the token from P11 will go down directly to the join node. P11 and P12 will pass their token down also with no issue, thereby creating that ghost token which gets stuck in the middle right join. Since the lower join now has two tokens it will continue to the end where the activity is terminated. At that point any free running tokens (and even active actions) are terminated as well. All good.

I leave my former answer for further inspiration. But basically they will all be implemented in similar ways since they represent a gateway.

---

**Original answer**

I guess that using an event would be the best way:

[image]

This way `D` can only start (and finish) when the event has been received which is sent after `A`s completion.

Another way would be to use an object that stores the finalization of action `A` and which is read by `D`.

[image]

Note that the diagonal connectors through `a ready` are `ObjectFlow`s which UML does not per default distinguish optically (unlike SysML).

P. 374 of UML 2.5 states

> Object tokens pass over ObjectFlows, carrying data through an Activity via their values, or carrying no data ( null tokens). A null token can still be passed along an ObjectFlow and used like any other token. For example, an Action can output a null token to explicitly indicate that it did not produce an optional value, and a downstream DecisionNode (see sub clause 15.3) can test for this and branch accordingly.

So you can see that as a buffer holding a token and no real data is needed to be stored. Basically that's the same as an event. Implementation wise you would use a semaphore or a stream to realize that, but of course at this level you would not care too much about such details.

Comment: using an event - if the condition of the second process is not met, the token “hangs” before D

Comment: 1. It will be destroyed as soon as the activity is finalized (which happens in any case).

Comment: The event is a very elegant approach. It seems on one side very practical, as it looks like popular real-life implementations of complex step by step synchronization.  On the other side it seems also theoretically equivalent, as the event passes the token from left flow to right flow, and as multiple entry points are an implicit join. Bravo!

Comment: I just had another look at the OP's diagram and it now seems as if he saw issues where there are none. His solution is ok. Must amend my answer...

Comment: Perhaps I should have made it clear at the outset that the example is only meant to illustrate the problem. I want a common solution. All proposed solutions, including mine, have a common drawback: the token "hangs" and will be destroyed as soon as the activity is completed. But in a "real" diagram, before the activity is completed, it is possible to re-enter the specified fragment. It is necessary to ensure the destruction of the token. The only way is to present the specified fragment as a compound activity and provide it with a FinalNode.